# Java EE 6 Security Model: How to add or delete user

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, security

I read most of the documentation, I only see the use of `@RolesAllowed` or `@DeclareRoles`, how can I add user or delete user. I have a table of users with username and password in my database, how can I make my web app to authenticate those user? How can I map these user (principal) to a particular roles. Samples code would be greatly appreciated. Thank you very much

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A JAAS Login module is required to authenticate the user, establish the principals, that can enable the mapping of users/principals existing in the database to roles defined in the source code.

Assuming that you are using GlassFish v3 for Java EE 6, you need to create and configure a JDBC realm in GlassFish for this purpose. Be forewarned that the realm configuration might not have a one-to-one mapping with the user table in your database, in which case you either need to modify the table definition, or extend the login module to create your own scheme.

Despite setting up the database realm, you would still need to map the Java EE roles defined in your source code, to the actual roles in the realm. That is accomplished using the application server specific deployment descriptors.

Comment: I know it would be too much to ask for samples code. But do you know any tutorial for this kind of things?

Comment: Well you're in luck. Have a look at the blog entry titled "Mort learns JDBC Realm authentication": http://blogs.sun.com/foo/entry/mort_learns_jdbc_realm_authentication

It shows how to configure a JDBC realm based of tables created by the author, and then shows how to use the users and roles in a very simple web application. Notice the mapping between the JEE role and the JDBC role in sun-web.xml

Comment: Great. Reading it now. I appreciated your help very much. Will let u know if I have any question. Once again. Thanks!

Comment: if anyone is looking for the blog entry, it's moved to: https://blogs.oracle.com/foo/entry/mort_learns_jdbc_realm_authentication

Comment: >`A JAAS Login module is required to authenticate the user` - This is A option, but not the only option. In Java EE 6 there's also JASPIC which defines an SPI for portable authentication modules.

Answer (score 1):

JavaEE doesn't define the management of users and roles, only how the application interacts with them.

It is up to the specific server implementations to define that functionality as they see fit.

Comment: Depending on what you exactly mean with "the management of users and roles" this may not be entirely true. In the context of OP's question I take it you mean that the implementation of an auth/login module isn't defined in Java EE. This is in fact defined; via the JASPIC SPI that was added in Java EE 6.